# summernote line breaks v0.8.8

Tags: summernote

I'm having an issue i've seen others post about, using the Enter key is causing an extra line break to appear.  Now I know I can use shift + enter, but i can't except my users to know that.

Is there a fix for this? I've using v0.8.8, I saw this:
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546#issuecomment-341518461

but this did not work, i saw another post using $.summernote.addPlugin({
but .addPlugin does not work in v0.8.8 anymore.

Was anyone able to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to change the functionality of Enter

```
$('#summernote').summernote().on("summernote.enter", function(we, e) {
  $(this).summernote('pasteHTML', '<br>&VeryThinSpace;');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

It's works for me.
Ref:- [Github](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546#issuecomment-683310325)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is at this link by [summernote breakline paragraph to br](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546#issuecomment-341518461)

all credit to Ghylt